# Zurb Foundation 4 on mobile device

Tags: web-applications, zurb-foundation, swipe-gesture

I used zurb foundation 4 for my project, it work well but when I try to swipe horizontally with a finger (on mobile device) does this:

[image: ipad view]

instead, i want it fixed for the width.

any tips are welcome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the **meta** tag for your **viewport** to the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

This will fix your issue and consequently disable zoom. Since most native applications don't allow zooming of the entire interface this shouldn't be much of an issue as long as your UI design is targeting the device.

Comment: it work, thanks chrisjsherm.
But if you can try jquerymobile docs demo you can notice zoom is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Put this in application layout

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1" />
```